# requesting HW specs

Tags: discussion

Wouldn't be possible to suggest to the user to add HW specs when asking hardware related questions?

I find myself asking over and over again "what's you laptop make/model?", "what's your GPU?", "how much ram do you have?" and so on.

Wondering if it would be possible to add a reminder to the user once the system detects a HW related question (the same way you detect similar posts).

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to fix in this question: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7189/need-help-what-problems-would-be-best-solved-by-a-wizard

Comment: that's very interesting. thanks for the heads-up, sorry for not spotting it before posting this. Your idea is even more ambitious. what I'm suggesting is just something like `if keywords == 'laptop|video card|memory|...' then ask for hardware info`. But if you can do what you are suggesting, well even better.