# How do I change my username on Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: support

How do I change my Ask Ubuntu username? I pressed enter by accident and now I have this one.

Answer (score 9):

You can change the display name easily. Go to [your user profile page](https://askubuntu.com/users/current), and look for:

[image: 'edit']

Click the edit button, and you should be able to change it via this:

[image: Display Name editing bit]

Then press one of the orange buttons at the bottom of the page:
[image: 'Save Profile' or 'Save and copy....' - your choice really.]

---

Also this might occur if you try changing it to often:
[image: Oops! There was a problem updating your profile: - Display name may only be changed once every 30 days; you may change again on Mar 14 at 16:23]

Which now means I cannot change the capital `W`...  :(

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me

Comment: In that case, the little tick to the left of my answer is what you need to press - it closes the question as answered, and would mean [slightly less bad statistics](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8333/unanswered-questions-what-to-do) on Meta... :)

Comment: @rajlego: If this answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Comment: Thanks for tellin me, I wouldn't have known :)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to change it from your profile page ([shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/users/edit/current)).

But if you can't change it, let me know what you want it to be and I can edit it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the offer

Comment: Uh oh It's not letting me, can you change it to rajlego please?

Comment: I've made the edit. Welcome.