# How can it be possible to have answers older than the question?

Tags: support

Does StackExchange have a time machine, or is this just from when questions have been merged?

Nice set of results on these precognitive questions [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/171088/precognitive-answers#resultSets) - Worst one is [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320632/why-do-i-need-to-type-before-executing-a-program-in-the-current-directory).

***Source:*** [This](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8575/178596) answer, which I recommend your read - also has a few interesting points on Zombie questions...

Comment: Dates don't change when posts are merged, so yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It was the result of a merge.](https://askubuntu.com/posts/320632/revisions)

Comment: Thanks - should of asked a better question anyway.