# Where can I find statistics about askubuntu?

Tags: support, statistics

I mostly want to know the rate of increase of askubuntu's question number. Anyhow where can I find this and other interesting statistics about this website?

Comment: You can start here http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-percentanswered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This great answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8575/178596) to a question I asked a while back uses [StackExchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/help) to do some simply brilliant graphs - you might find [this one](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph?Weeks=150#graph) interesting:

[image: graph]

<sup>You may need to login to stackExchange Data Explorer to view the graph and stuff</sup>

Comment: That page, including the graph it produces, is viewable in the Data Explorer even without logging in. (I just tested to see.)

Comment: @EliahKagan I know, but it started throwing CAPTCHAs at me as I was not logged in, which I don't like, so I just logged in.

Comment: now that's what I'm talking about!!!! thanks :D