# Why nobody answers my latest questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions

It's obviously that my latest questions received low views, no votes and nobody answered.

> [image]

I use to mark the correct answers, so if you find good answers for these questions, post them.

[**Here you can find my questions.**](https://askubuntu.com/users/148451?tab=questions&sort=newest)

Comment: Because most of the unanswered questions of your's are about hardwares(like printers, touchpads,etc), chances of having these kind of devices among people are low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to look this is that you are not the only one who is not having questions answered - as I sort of covered [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8333/unanswered-questions-what-to-do) a while ago, AskUbuntu has the [second-lowest](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#percentanswered) amount of answered questions:

[image: 66% answered]
<sup>*Note this depends on whether answered questions count as 'questions with answers', or 'questions marked as answered' (or something completely different....)</sup>

Comment: Is questions marked as answered where answered means "at least one upvoted or accepted answer".

Comment: @Braiam - could be...